# Python os how to accept verification for SSH key

Tags: python, bash, terminal, python-os

So basically I have a function that launches a glue development endpoint, and I want to programmatically launch zeppelin, then use the IP from the endpoint to ssh into it with my local browser. To do so, I run the following commands in the terminal:

```
cd ~/zepp081
bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start
ssh -i pem_file_path -NTL 9007:169.254.76.1:9007 glue@ip_address
```

When I run the last command, I get the prompt:

```
The authenticity of host 'ip_address' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is X.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

at which point I type `yes` and continue on with my life. I would like to automate this in python using the following command:

```
import os

ssh_string = "ssh -i pem_file_path -NTL 9007:169.254.76.1:9007 glue@ip_address"
os.system(f"cd ~/zepp081 && bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start && {ssh_string}")
```

The first two commands in line 4 run successfully, but the third fails saying `Host key verification failed.` How can I update the command to have it continue connecting?

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" .....
```

Comment: when I update the command to `ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" file_path -NTL 9007:169.254.76.1:9007 glue@ip`

I get the error `ssh: Could not resolve hostname file_path_to_PEM: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Comment: Did you leave out the `-i pem_`, or was the above a typo?

Comment: I replaced `-i pem_` with `-o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no"`

Comment: This was just supposed to be an additional argument, not a replacement.

Comment: understood, where should I put it though?